# Syntastic doesn't work in combination with vim signify

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, syntastic

Here is a snippet of my .vimrc

```
nnoremap <leader>p "0p 
xnoremap <leader>p "0p 
nnoremap <leader>d "_d 
xnoremap <leader>d "_d 
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
  Plug 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
  Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
  Plug 'mhinz/vim-signify'
  Plug 'helino/vim-json'
  Plug 'rking/ag.vim'
  Plug 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides'
  Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'
  Plug 'scrooloose/syntastic'
call plug#end()


set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1 
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1 
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1 
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0 
let g:syntastic_loc_list_height=1
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'passive', 'active_filetypes': [],'passive_filetypes': [] }
nnoremap <leader>E :SyntasticCheck<CR> :SyntasticToggleMode<CR>
```

Prior to adding syntastic to my vim, vim-signify worked just fine, but after adding syntastic, vim-signify no longer works. I installed jshint using node globally (npm install -g jshint).

Also when I turn on SyntasticCheck(using `<leader>E`) my vim crashes randomly, happens 2 out of 10 times.
Can someone throw some light on whats happening here?

Comment: Both plugins use the *sign* feature. You should try their respective issue trackers.

Comment: (1) Syntastic seems to get along fine with `signify`, provided that you enable the latter by setting `g:signify_vcs_list`.  If that doesn't fix your problem, the issue tracker is [this way](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues). (2) Crashes are unrelated to syntastic, and probably also unrelated to `signify`.  (3) Running `:SyntasticCheck` and `:SyntasticToggleMode` together doesn't make sense.